# why i am not able to refer to resources of my raw folder

Tags: android

i am trying to refer to a music in raw folder but some error are there.it says `explosion cannot be resolved or is not a field`.can anyone tell me what could be the reason.

```
package com.app1;

import android.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.SoundPool;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class SoundStuff extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
SoundPool sp;
    int explosion=0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        View v= new View(this);
        v.setOnClickListener(this);
        setContentView(v);
        sp=new SoundPool(5,AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,0);
        **explosion=sp.load(SoundStuff.this, R.raw.explosion, 1);**
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(explosion!=0)
        sp.play(explosion, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);

    }


}
```

code is given above.line of code which shows error is already marked.

Comment: clean your project and recheck

Comment: recheck in the folder res/raw : explosion file is present or not ?

Answer (score 6):

Delete the `import android.R;` line. When you are using `R.raw.explosion`, you mean the R variable that is in `android.R`.

Make sure that when you are using R variable you mean one that is in your package:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of R which can be added .. Always add R associated with your package..